# Save data in object using KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, save

I am new to KnockoutJS. I have a form with multiple controls - checkboxes, option buttons, textboxes, etc. On Save button click, instead of reading values from individual controls or view model and making ajax call to save data, I need to save the data entered into an object, convert the object to JSON,

```
var x =  ko.toJSON(ObjectwithData());
```

and then using ajax, call the save routine.
Please guide how can I accomplish this. I you have sample code which does that, it would be great.

Comment: The post currently reads more like a generic to do, than a question. Could you include an [mcve] and tell us where the *specific* problem or question lies?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear but here is this what I understood.

You need to bind all your data from your form to a Json object.

for eg:

at Html:

```
<div id="root">
  <p>Name</p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" />
  </p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:Email" />
  </p>
  <p>Phone</p>
  <p>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:Phone" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button id="submit" data-bind="click:submit">Submit</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

at Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewModel = function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.Email = ko.observable("");
    self.Phone = ko.observable("");

    self.submit = function(){
    var postData = self.koToJson();

    }

    self.koToJson = function(){
    return {
    Name : self.Name(),
    Email: self.Email(),
    Phone: self.Phone()
    };
    }

  }
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);



});
```

Here the `self.koToJson` function is used to convert KO data to Json.

for more info please visit this jsFiddile https://jsfiddle.net/ninshidme/nk45Lvnv/4/

If this helps you don't forget to mark it as answer.

Happy Coding.